# read urls with wildcards from a list and download using lftp

Tags: bash, curl, ftp, wget, lftp

Is there a way to use `lftp` to download a bunch of files by reading urls from a file?

My input looks like this:

```
$ cat urls.txt
ftp://ftp.example.com/123*/*.jpg
ftp://ftp.example.com/234*/*.png
ftp://ftp.example.com/345*/*.pdf
```

If these were full urls without the wildcards, I would use `wget -i urls.txt` but that does not work because of the `*` in the middle of the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare a list of commands and feed them to lftp. Something like this:

while read url; do echo mget $url; done < urls.txt | lftp